# Ember.js - Add Components dynamically to a View

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I would like to be able to dynamically add `<li>` elements (which are implemented as a Component), to an  element (to which I can get reference from the View).

I have the following code:

```
...
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/team-effort">
  <li>
    <button {{action remove}}>remove</button>
  </li>
</script>
...

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">.
    <button {{action "addNewTeamEffort" target="view"}}>Add New Team</button><br />
    <ul id="teameffortul">
       {{team-effort}}
    </ul>  
</script>

App.TeamEffortComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        console.log('didInsertElement - TeamEffortComponent');
    },
    actions: {
        remove: function(){
            this.remove();
            console.log('removed a component');
        }
    }
});

and finally the view:

    App.ProjectsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "projects",
    didInsertElement: function(){
        jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();
    },
    actions: {
        addNewTeamEffort: function(){
            App.TeamEffortComponent.create().appendTo(jQuery('#teameffortul'));
            console.log('added team effort!');
        }
    }
});
```

whenever I click the "Add new Team button" the appropriate method is called in the View and I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.
```

When I have:

```
addNewTeamEffort: function(){
                jQuery('#teameffortul').append('<li>test</li>');
                console.log('added team effort!');
            }
```

instead of:

```
addNewTeamEffort: function(){
                App.TeamEffortComponent.create().appendTo(jQuery('#teameffortul'));
                console.log('added team effort!');
            }
```

it works as expected, and `<li>` element is appended to the `<ul>`. Can you spot what my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by adding the `templateName` explicitly like this:

```
App.TeamEffortComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    templateName: "components/team-effort",
    ...
```

You can see a working [JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/axUNIJE/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Scott! Thanks for the answer mate, it works indeed! However, still in the console I am getting the same error, namely: Assertion failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead. Even tho it adds the new elements I feel a bit uneasy about this error. Can you post a simple code whereby you use containerView instead of my approach? Thanks!

Comment: @Dragan Yeah give me a few minutes and I will see what I can do. Cheers, Scott